# I need to only show two rows on my Google Charts table

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I need to only show two rows on my Google Charts table. I currently have the following that is being called:

```
function drawTable() {
    var jsonData = '@Html.Raw(ViewData["totalsTable"])';

    var table;
    var data;
    var options;

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    options = { 'pageSize': 2 };

    table.draw(data, options);        

}
```

The problem being that this is showing a table with all of the values from the DataTable. I just want to show the first two rows. options = { 'pageSize': 2 } is supposed to achieve this. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Paging is disabled by default; you have to enable it by setting the `page` option to `'enable'`:

```
options = {
    page: 'enable',
    pageSize: 2
};
```

**[Edit - instructions on how to display a specific set of rows only, without paging]**

If you want to display a specific set of rows, you can use a DataView to restrict the rows displayed:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
// the #setRows method takes an array of row indices as an argument
// display the first two rows only (indices 0 and 1):
view.setRows([0, 1]);
// use the view to draw your table instead of the DataTable:
table.draw(view, options);
```

Incidentally, you don't have to put quotes around the output of `@Html.Raw(ViewData["totalsTable"])` if it is valid JSON.  Leaving them out is moderately more efficient, as the Visualization API won't have to convert your JSON into a javascript object:

```
var jsonData = @Html.Raw(ViewData["totalsTable"]);
```

Comment: Yeah. I just realized that paging is needed after coming across another stackoverflow post. However, I really don't want the buttons at the bottom, and what I'd really like to be able to do is only show two rows at any given point in time.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different story.  I'll update my answer with instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'pageSize' option to work, paging must be enabled.

```
options = { 'pageSize': 2 };
```

Based on your post, I think you need the setColumns method. Documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=ja#DataView_setColumns